# How to apply multiple palettes to categorized data

Tags: qgis, symbology

How to apply multiple palettes to categorized data/

For example, I'd like to apply this palette to the 5 selected values rather than to all of them.

[image]

Comment: you can do this via the Style Manager https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/style_manager.html

Comment: @Mapperz can you show me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How I would do it IF you are sure about how you want to sort your values (5 by 5 or the first 3 values then the 7 others...) :

First, duplicate your layer.

In the new layer, classify all your values :

[image]

Delete the values you don't need (6 to 10 here) and reapply your palette, the remaining values will change color according to the palette :

[image]

Now, switch the symbology to rule-based symbology :

[image]

Copy all the created rules and paste them in the original layer (set in rule-based symbology). Repeat with the second palette and its associated values :

[image]

I have the a set values with two different palettes.

This method it not ideal, there might be a better way to achieve the same result.